# Blocking specific IP addresses with Jetty

Tags: jetty

What is the best/easiest way to block a specific IP address with Jetty 8? Apparently the HTAccessHandler no longer works for the current version (source: http://jetty.4.n6.nabble.com/jira-Created-JETTY-962-Clean-room-implementation-of-org-mortbay-jetty-securtiy-HTAccessHandler-td41205.html) so I was wondering if there is a built-in solution short of writing a custom Filter/Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Use the IPAccessHandler in jetty-server:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/IPAccessHandler.java

Comment: This class is now deprecated with `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler` as the replacement.